# Uml activity diagram - initial point and trigger event

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I have a UML activity diagram in which I want to document/explain the events which trigger the first activity. What is the UML recommendations for this? Should I write some text in the diagram as kind of pre-conditions? Should I insert a condition guard between the start point and the first activity ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You will use a guard like this:

[image]

This guard is usually derived from a pre-condition defined in the scenario of the according use case.